# Comparing dates from sheets

Tags: array, datetime, vba, excel

I am looking to increase the speed of this Excel VBA Nested Loop.  The loop compares dates from one sheet to a secondary sheet.  If they match, I change the border around the cell to highlight it.  It currently works fine, but takes about 30 seconds to process per sub. Is there a way to implement an array or other tactic to speed it up?

```
Sub Single()

Dim DateRng As Range, DateCell As Range, DateRngPay As Range
Dim cellA As Range
Dim cellB As Range
Dim myColor As Variant

Set DateRng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SS").Range("B11:F16,I11:M16,P11:t16,B19:F24,I19:M24,P19:t24,B27:F32,I27:M32,P27:t32,B35:F40,I35:M40,P35:t40")
Set DateRngPay = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PS").Range("C2:C67")
myColor = Array("38")

If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Info").Range("B67") = 1 Then
    With DateRng
            .Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
            .Borders.ColorIndex = 1
            .Borders.Weight = xlHairline
    For Each cellA In DateRng
        For Each cellB In DateRngPay
                If cellB.Value > "" And cellA.Value > "" And cellB.Value = cellA.Value Then
                With cellA.Borders
                    .ColorIndex = myColor
                    .Weight = xlMedium
                End With
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cellB
    Next cellA
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The first tip is to stop updating the screen while it runs: Application.ScreenUpdating = False and when you're done, turn it True again, It will give you some seconds of runtime, but will make Excel seem non-respondent

Comment: Thanks Fernando... I just tried it out and there was no improvement. I have tried it in the past also with no luck either.  I think the slow down is each cellA (300+) references each cellB (60+) which is 18,000+ times it has to check if the conditions are met

Comment: Then you need to stop reading them and updating so many times, just something out of thin air: - vectorA[] = readCellsValues; vectorB[] = readsCellsValues; compareThemAll and save results on another vectorC[]; write down result after comparisons.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the problem statement could be worded as "if any cell from a specific range in sheet 'SS' has a value that exists **anywhere** in sheet 'PS' between C2 and C67, we need to format that cell"?

Comment: That's correct Mat... We need to format the SS cell

Answer (score 3):

Normally I'd go on and ramble about how your procedure's name should start with a verb, how the casing of your local variables isn't consistently `camelCase`, how the procedure is *implicitly* `Public`, how the indentation is broken and therefore confusing here:

```
With DateRng
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        .Borders.ColorIndex = 1
        .Borders.Weight = xlHairline
For Each cellA In DateRng
    For Each cellB In DateRngPay
            If cellB.Value > "" And cellA.Value > "" And cellB.Value = cellA.Value Then
            With cellA.Borders
                .ColorIndex = myColor
                .Weight = xlMedium
            End With
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cellB
Next cellA
End With
```

Compare to:

```
With DateRng
    .Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    .Borders.ColorIndex = 1
    .Borders.Weight = xlHairline
    For Each cellA In DateRng
        For Each cellB In DateRngPay
            If cellB.Value > "" And cellA.Value > "" And cellB.Value = cellA.Value Then
                With cellA.Borders
                    .ColorIndex = myColor
                    .Weight = xlMedium
                End With
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cellB
    Next cellA
End With
```

...I'd also so mention that I find `cellB.Value > ""` a little weird when everyone else would have written `cellB.Value <> ""` or perhaps `cellB.Value <> vbNullString`.

I might even have wrecked my brains around trying to find a way to remove the need for a nested loop at all.

All of that would have been useful advice... but there's an even better one.

Ready?

---

Unless you have a VERY specific and cast-in-stone requirement for the border width, there's no need for any VBA code to do this.

First, name the range on `SS!$C$2:$C$67`, say `MyValues` - here I've populated the data with values 1-66, but anything will do:

[image: named range]

On the `PS` sheet, select cell `PS!$B$11` and create a *conditional format* for it, using this formula:

```
=AND(Info!$B$67=1,NOT(ISNA(MATCH(B11,MyValues,0))))
```

Decide how you want the conditional format to look like, and then change the *applies to* range to the cells you're interested in:

```
=$B$11:$F$16,$I$11:$M$16,$P$11:$T$16,$P$19:$T$24,$I$19:$M$24,$B$19:$F$24,$B$27:$F$32,$I$27:$M$32,$P$27:$T$32
```

[image: conditional format]

I've shaded these target cells on my own sheet here, but as you can see, any value in these cells that's present on `MyValues` gets a yellow background and a black border...

[image: conditional formats]

...instantaneously.

Comment: Thank you for the response Mat.  I am familiar with conditional formatting, but unfortunately I do need the specifics of VBA to allow for more customization. Also, sorry for the case and formatting...I've never had formal coding classes and definitely lack on the finesse.

Answer (score 2):

Sticking to VBA, here is my contribution

---

**1. Use built in function**

excel or VBA built in functions are much faster then any cells iteration

searching for matching cells is a common Excel task you can accomplish with [Find()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) method

this way you only need to iterate through `DateRng` cells and search for any matching cell in `DateRngPay` like follows:

```
    For Each cell In DateRng '<--| loop through 'DateRng' cells           
        Set f = DateRngPay.Find(what:=cell.value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) '<--| look in 'DateRngPay' for a cell matching current 'DateRng' one
        If Not f Is Nothing Then 
            With f.Borders
               .ColorIndex = 38
               .Weight = xlMedium
            End With
        End If
    Next cell
```

---

**2. Act on grouped cells**

acting on many cells one by one is time consuming

so you'd much better group them in one single range object and act on it

you can accomplish this with Excel [Union()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx) method like follows:

```
    Dim unionRng as Range '<--| this range will store all 'DateRng' cells matching any 'DateRng' one
    For Each cell In DateRng '<--| loop through 'DateRng' cells           
        Set f = DateRngPay.Find(what:=cell.value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) '<--| look in 'DateRngPay' for a cell matching current 'DateRng' one
        If Not f Is Nothing Then '<--| if a match has been found, then update 'unionRng'
            If unionRng Is Nothing Then '<--| if 'unionRng' has already been set
                Set unionRng = f
            Else
                Set unionRng = Union(f, unionRng)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

    If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then '<--| if at least one matching cell has been found, then format them in one shot!
        With unionRng.Borders
           .ColorIndex = 38
           .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
    End If
```

where that `If unionRng Is Nothing Then` takes care not to have `Set unionRng = Union(f, unionRng)` fail at first matching cell, where `unionRng` range would still be `Nothing`: we'll come back here in a while.

---

**3. Summary#1**

for what above, a first refactoring of your code could be the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Single1()
    Dim DateRng As Range, DateRngPay As Range '<--| working ranges
    Dim cell As Range, f As Range '<--| ranges used for lookup tasks
    Dim unionRng As Range '<--| this range will store all 'DateRng' cells matching any 'DateRng' one

    Set DateRng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SS").Range("B11:F16,I11:M16,P11:t16,B19:F24,I19:M24,P19:t24,B27:F32,I27:M32,P27:t32,B35:F40,I35:M40,P35:t40")
    Set DateRngPay = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PS").Range("C2:C67")

    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Info").Range("B67") = 1 Then
        With DateRng
            .Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
            .Borders.ColorIndex = 1
            .Borders.Weight = xlHairline
            For Each cell In .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| loop through 'DateRng' non blank cells
                Set f = DateRngPay.Find(what:=cell.value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) '<--| look in 'DateRngPay' for a cell matching current 'DateRng' one
                If Not f Is Nothing Then '<--| if a match has been found, then update 'unionRng'
                    If unionRng Is Nothing Then '<--| if 'unionRng' has already been set
                        Set unionRng = cell
                    Else
                        Set unionRng = Union(cell, unionRng)
                    End If
                End If
            Next cell
        End With
        If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then '<--| if at least one matching cell has been found, then format them in one shot!
            With unionRng.Borders
               .ColorIndex = 38
               .Weight = xlMedium
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

which should already boost it quite up!

But more is yet to come...

**4. Avoid useless `IF -Then` statements**

In previous code we have two of such IF statements:

```
            If Not f Is Nothing Then '<--| if a match has been found, then update 'unionRng'
                If unionRng Is Nothing Then '<--| if 'unionRng' has already been set
                    Set unionRng = cell
                Else
                    Set unionRng = Union(cell, unionRng)
                End If
            End If
```

the *inner* `If` can be avoided with a little trick:

1. set `unionRng` just before the `For Each cell In DateRng loop`:

   ```
   Set unionRng = somecell '<--| initialize unionRng not to bother about feeding first 'Union()' method with a 'null' range
   ```

   now you can go straight with `Union()` method:

   ```
       Set unionRng = somecell
       For Each cell In .Cells '<--| loop through 'DateRng' cells
           Set f = DateRngPay.Find(what:=cell.value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) '<--| look in 'DateRngPay' for a cell matching current 'DateRng' one
           If Not f Is Nothing Then Set unionRng = Union(cell, unionRng) '<--| if a match has been found, then update 'unionRng'
       Next cell
   ```

   but here we end up with a *false* matching cell (i.e.: `somecell`) in `unionRng` at the end of the searching loop.
2. initialize `unionRng` to a range that's certainly outside the *looped* one (i.e. `DateRng`):

   ```
   Set unionRng = DateRng.Offset(-1, -1).Resize(1, 1) '<--| initialize 'unionRng' to a cell out of searched range
   ```

   this way you just need to use Excel [Intersect()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835030.aspx) method to *purge* that initializing (and not matching) cell out of `unionRng`:

   ```
   Set unionRng = Intersect(unionRng, DateRng.Cells) '<--| "purge" the initializing (and not matching) cell out of 'unionRng'
   ```

---

**5. Summary #2**

refactoring point 3 code with point 4 technique we come up to:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Single2()
    Dim DateRng As Range, DateRngPay As Range '<--| working ranges
    Dim cell As Range, f As Range '<--| ranges used for lookup tasks
    Dim unionRng As Range '<--| this range will store all 'DateRng' cells matching any 'DateRng' one

    Set DateRng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SS").Range("B11:F16,I11:M16,P11:t16,B19:F24,I19:M24,P19:t24,B27:F32,I27:M32,P27:t32,B35:F40,I35:M40,P35:t40")
    Set DateRngPay = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PS").Range("C2:C67")

    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Info").Range("B67") = 1 Then
        With DateRng
            .Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
            .Borders.ColorIndex = 1
            .Borders.Weight = xlHairline
            Set unionRng = DateRng.Offset(-1, -1).Cells(1, 1) '<--| initialize 'unionRng' to a cell out of searched range
            For Each cell In .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| loop through 'DateRng' non blank cells
                Set f = DateRngPay.Find(what:=cell.value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) '<--| look in 'DateRngPay' for a cell matching current 'DateRng' one
                If Not f Is Nothing Then Set unionRng = Union(cell, unionRng) '<--| if a match has been found, then update 'unionRng'
            Next cell
            Set unionRng = Intersect(unionRng, .Cells) '<--| "purge" the initializing (and not matching) cell out of 'unionRng'
        End With
        If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then '<--| if at least one matching cell has been found, then format them in one shot!
            With unionRng.Borders
               .ColorIndex = 38
               .Weight = xlMedium
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

---

**6. Do thing when it's time to**

doing things before their time is quite a *hidden* way to consume time uselessly

for instance:

```
Set DateRng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SS").Range("B11:F16,I11:M16,P11:t16,B19:F24,I19:M24,P19:t24,B27:F32,I27:M32,P27:t32,B35:F40,I35:M40,P35:t40")
Set DateRngPay = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PS").Range("C2:C67")

If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Info").Range("B67") = 1 Then
```

have your code do things (i.e. range settings) even if they should become useless after "Info" sheet "B67" cell check

the correct logic would be:

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Info").Range("B67") <> 1 Then Exit Sub '<--| exit if "continue" condition isn't met

Set DateRng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SS").Range("B11:F16,I11:M16,P11:t16,B19:F24,I19:M24,P19:t24,B27:F32,I27:M32,P27:t32,B35:F40,I35:M40,P35:t40")
Set DateRngPay = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PS").Range("C2:C67")

With DateRng
    ....
```

these range settings are quite harmless in this specific case, but keep that in mind and avoid making useless and long calculations (both by excel - changing a worksheet cell in a *automatic* calculation mode - or by your code - calling some *long* subs).

---

**7. Avoid processing useless cells**

Use [SpecialCells()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) method of `Range` object to select only its relevant cells to work with

in this specific case we're only interested in *numbers* (since dates are numbers) so we could filter our working ranges like follows:

```
Set DateRngPay = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PS").Range("C2:C67").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
```

---

**8. Miscellanea**

Though not being strictly related to the code time performance issue, some coding techniques should be followed to have your code more readable and thus maintainable and upgradeable

which is code performance, too...

**Divide et Impera**

Romans empire lasted 2 thousands years on this principle, so there must e be something good in it to exploit for us (even if Romans didn't code for PC's...)

your code would be much easier to read both for you and upcoming people if written in such a way as the following:

```
Sub Main

   DoThis

   DoThat

End Sub
```

this would have you really concentrate on relevant bits of your code without a coast-to-coast searching and scrolling of a long code

this will also have the benefit to use variables only when needed and thus both unclutter you code from long variables declaration blocks and improving memory occupation (should that ever be an issue)

for instance, analyzing this *declaration* block:

```
Dim DateRng As Range, DateRngPay As Range '<--| working ranges
Dim cell As Range, f As Range '<--| ranges used for lookup tasks
Dim unionRng As Range '<--| this range will store all 'DateRng' cells matching any 'DateRng' one
```

there would arise the issue we can keep first line in our main sub, while shifting other lines to specific subs/functions

**Search for patterns and use them**

this, again, to improve code readability, maintenance and upgrading:

for instance

```
.Range("B11:F16,I11:M16,P11:t16,B19:F24,I19:M24,P19:t24,B27:F32,I27:M32,P27:t32,B35:F40,I35:M40,P35:t40")
```

seems quite a not meaningful range specification while you very well know it does follow a *pattern*

so use and take advantage of that in your possible future code enhancements

**9. Summary# 3**

a possible (final?) refactoring could be the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Single3()
    Dim DateRng As Range, DateRngPay As Range

    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Info").Range("B67") <> 1 Then Exit Sub '<--| exit if continue condition isn't met

    Set DateRng = SetRange(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SS").Range("B11:F16"), 3, 2, 4, 2)
    Set DateRngPay = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PS").Range("C2:C67")

    FirstFormat DateRng
    HighlightCells GetDatesCells(DateRngPay, DateRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers))
End Sub

Function GetDatesCells(DateRngPay As Range, DateRng As Range) As Range
    Dim unionRng As Range, f As Range, cell As Range

    Set unionRng = DateRng.Offset(-1, -1)
    With DateRngPay
        For Each cell In DateRng
            Set f = .Find(what:=cell.value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not f Is Nothing Then Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, cell)
        Next cell
    End With
    Set GetDatesCells = Intersect(unionRng, DateRng)
End Function

Sub HighlightCells(rng As Range)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then '<--| if any cell has been found then
        With rng.Borders '<--| reference their 'Borders' property
            .ColorIndex = 38
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Sub FirstFormat(rng As Range)
    With rng
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        .Borders.ColorIndex = 1
        .Borders.Weight = xlHairline
    End With
End Sub

Function SetRange(rng As Range, colsRepeat As Long, colSpacing As Long, rowsRepeat As Long, rowSpacing As Long)
    Dim iRow As Long, jCol As Long

    Set SetRange = rng
    With rng
        For iRow = 1 To rowsRepeat
            For jCol = 1 To colsRepeat
                Set SetRange = Union(SetRange, .Offset((iRow - 1) * (.Rows.Count + rowSpacing), (jCol - 1) * (.Columns.Count + colSpacing)))
            Next jCol
        Next iRow
    End With
End Function
```

where you are invited to find and use different and more meaningful subs/functions names

Finally, me being a fan of *short* code, I'd hereby post a possible further shortening of `GetDatesCells()` sub

```
Function GetDatesCells(DateRngPay As Range, DateRng As Range) As Range
    Dim unionRng As Range, f As Range, cell As Range

    Set unionRng = DateRng.Offset(-1, -1)
    With DateRngPay
        For Each cell In DateRng
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, cell.value) > 0 Then Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, cell)
        Next cell
    End With
    Set GetDatesCells = Intersect(unionRng, DateRng)
End Function
```

Comment: Wow, that's some epic answer! Lots of good stuff here, well done!

Comment: @Mat'sMug, thank you. Not so sure the OP will come back to this thread, though.

Comment: Great post user3598756!  I haven't forgot about you... been busy and just trying out each solution now.  I've been trying to also figure out some of the bugs myself.  So solution 1 works and there is some speed up, but it also highlights any blank cells.  Solution 2 throws a application error at set unionRng = dateRng. And Solution 3 states HighlightCells GetDateCells is blank.  I don't have any formal training for coding and I may be missing something obvious.  I do love to learn so I really appreciate the explanations with your post.

Comment: @jb3700, edited solution 1 and 2 to handle (exclude)`DateRng`blank cells. This has been done by _filtering_ the range with the use of [`Specialcells()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) method of `Range` object. However I can't get you with solution 3 issue: what does _" states HighlightCells GetDateCells is blank"_ mean?